# How to find last cluster in pandas data frame row?

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7

If I have a Pandas data frame like this:

```
     A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J
 1   1  NaN  1   1  NaN  1  NaN  1   1   1
 2  NaN NaN  1  NaN  1   1   1   1  NaN NaN
 3  NaN NaN NaN  1   1   1  NaN  1   1  NaN
 4   1   1   1   1  NaN NaN NaN  1   1  NaN
```

How do I find the last cluster of values in every row such that I get a data frame like this:

```
     A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J
 1  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  1   1   1
 2  NaN NaN NaN NaN  1   1   1   1  NaN NaN
 3  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  1   1  NaN
 4  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  1   1  NaN
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC using `cumsum` with Boolean filter

```
s=df.isnull().cumsum(1)
df=df[s.eq(s[df.notnull()].max(1),axis=0)]
df
Out[17]: 
    A   B   C   D    E    F    G  H    I    J
1 NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1  1.0  1.0
2 NaN NaN NaN NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1  NaN  NaN
3 NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1  1.0  NaN
4 NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1  1.0  NaN
```